# Why am I getting the same result when requesting MySQL with different parameters?

Tags: mysql

tell me why I get such a strange result, I have a simple table in mysql in which there is only 1 row

| id | api_key | product_id | request_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | aaa | bbb | 1616229665 |

And there is a stored function that looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`master`@`localhost` FUNCTION `master`.`test`(api_key varchar(36),product_id varchar(36)) RETURNS int
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE login_count int;
    DECLARE login_api_key int;
    DECLARE time_stamp int;
    DECLARE last_request_time int;
    DECLARE time_out int;
    SET time_out = 10;
    SET time_stamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
    SET last_request_time = (SELECT id from connections_mt where `api_key` = api_key and `product_id` = product_id limit 1);
    return last_request_time;
END
```

Okay...

> SELECT test('aaa','bbb');

```
test('aaa','sdfc')|
------------------|
                 7|
```

Correct!

> SELECT test('aaa','sdfc');

```
test('aaa','sdfc')|
------------------|
                 7|
```

WTF?! * _ *

WAT? - What is happening I do not understand it should not have found anything, and return null records that satisfy this condition does not exist and it finds yes and even the wrong one...

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It seems that this is some kind of tricky cache, but I do not understand how to get rid of it.

Comment: Change the name of your input parameters, so they are not the same as your field names.

Comment: Thank you I don't know why but it worked!

Comment: Mysql can get confused  if product_id means the field or the variable.

Comment: Write this as an answer so I can mark it with a solution :)